# YouTube's Playlists.list API endpoint is returning only one item

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm using the YouTube Data API to fetch playlists from a channel.
Although the API its just returning one item I have more than 1 video.

I'm using this command to fetch the lists from the API:

`curl 'https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlists/part=snippet&id=PLnCjPY6asmJHeiIIkpRyTQEMrxHrWtZ7k&maxResults=50&key=[YOUR_API_KEY]' --header 'Accept: application/json' --compressed`.

My playlists are:

`https://youtube.com/playlistlist=PLnCjPY6asmJHeiIIkpRyTQEMrxHrWtZ7k`

and

`https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PLnCjPY6asmJGdMJsGrSO4XRC4HNPGrr2O`.

Comment: Please follow [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) guide lines.

Comment: You should provide a minimal code sample to demonstrate your effort to resolve the issue. From your question it is not obvious what way you utilize YouTube API. It is obvious that you try to use [Playlists: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlists/list) -- the page has __Try this API__ which offers several methods: curl, http, javascript, Java, PHP, Python (if you correctly fill provided form which capable to generate result, then you can copy sample code to utilize for your purpose).

Comment: You can try use web browser with following __URL__: `https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlists?part=snippet&channelId=UCywL8mGqZfMuW1XHHd-CUAQ&maxResults=50&key=[YOUR_API_KEY]`

Answer (score 0):

The first link provided above:

`https://youtube.com/playlistlist=PLnCjPY6asmJHeiIIkpRyTQEMrxHrWtZ7k`

produces a 404 HTTP error.

This may well imply that the respective playlist is non-public or, otherwise, it does not exist.

But that playlist exists and is public:

```bash
$ curl -sS "https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlists?part=snippet,status,contentDetails&id=PLnCjPY6asmJHeiIIkpRyTQEMrxHrWtZ7k&key=$YOUTUBE_DATA_APP_KEY"
{
  "kind": "youtube#playlistListResponse",
  "etag": "ikd5nTpw3-0X4LHo3x8VJI4zR3Y",
  "pageInfo": {
    "totalResults": 1,
    "resultsPerPage": 5
  },
  "items": [
    {
      "kind": "youtube#playlist",
      "etag": "wvJ0oJ4J-sYprm_GEoG_hC52rfw",
      "id": "PLnCjPY6asmJHeiIIkpRyTQEMrxHrWtZ7k",
      "snippet": {
        "publishedAt": "2019-07-16T15:28:17Z",
        "channelId": "UCywL8mGqZfMuW1XHHd-CUAQ",
        "title": "Novidades da semana no Cantinho de Casa",
        "description": "",
        "thumbnails": {
          ...
        },
        "channelTitle": "Cantinho de casa",
        "localized": {
          "title": "Novidades da semana no Cantinho de Casa",
          "description": ""
        }
      },
      "status": {
        "privacyStatus": "public"
      },
      "contentDetails": {
        "itemCount": 162
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Please acknowledge that the YouTube Data API is functioning correctly when invoked for its [`Playlists.list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlists/list) endpoint queried with the request parameter [`id`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlists/list#id): you give one playlist ID as input to the endpoint, thus you obtain only one playlist metadata in response.

One the other hand, if you need to *list all playlists* of a channel, then you should invoke `Playlists.list` with the request parameter [`channelId`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlists/list#channelId) set to the respective channel's ID, instead of using the request parameter [`id`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlists/list#id).

Answer (score -1):

Please try following command, it was tested with my **API_KEY** and **ACCESS_TOKEN**.

```
curl \
  'https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet&maxResults=50&playlistId=PLnCjPY6asmJGbeZjj2f261il27IvHmR3C&key=[YOUR_API_KEY]' \
  --header 'Authorization: Bearer [YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN]' \
  --header 'Accept: application/json' \
  --compressed
```

Result (for default maxResults=5)

```
{
  "kind": "youtube#playlistItemListResponse",
  "etag": "4aX3dHqSQuLyAE655g5XBSX_p1o",
  "nextPageToken": "CAUQAA",
  "items": [
    {
      "kind": "youtube#playlistItem",
      "etag": "bGUNJZR2SBU2qric_hoFQouqwn8",
      "id": "UExuQ2pQWTZhc21KR2JlWmpqMmYyNjFpbDI3SXZIbVIzQy5BRjJDODk5REM0NjkzMUIy",
      "snippet": {
        "publishedAt": "2019-07-02T16:59:48Z",
        "channelId": "UCywL8mGqZfMuW1XHHd-CUAQ",
        "title": "Como fazer muda de rosa por estaca em 5 dias jeito mais fácil que existe!",
        "description": "Gente confira minha última técnica de geração de mudas de rosas que eu criei que é muito mais muito mais fácil e eficiente: https://youtu.be/tH3wZ2Hd1_I\n\nLivro do Cantinho de casa: https://youtu.be/al-ylS2tkSw  espero que goste pois ficou maravilhoso! abraços\nAssine o Cantinho de casa: https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCywL8mGqZfMuW1XHHd-CUAQ?sub_confirmation=1",
        "thumbnails": {
          "default": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/Fw2x4tlmwG4/default.jpg",
            "width": 120,
            "height": 90
          },
          "medium": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/Fw2x4tlmwG4/mqdefault.jpg",
            "width": 320,
            "height": 180
          },
          "high": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/Fw2x4tlmwG4/hqdefault.jpg",
            "width": 480,
            "height": 360
          },
          "standard": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/Fw2x4tlmwG4/sddefault.jpg",
            "width": 640,
            "height": 480
          }
        },
        "channelTitle": "Cantinho de casa",
        "playlistId": "PLnCjPY6asmJGbeZjj2f261il27IvHmR3C",
        "position": 0,
        "resourceId": {
          "kind": "youtube#video",
          "videoId": "Fw2x4tlmwG4"
        },
        "videoOwnerChannelTitle": "Cantinho de casa",
        "videoOwnerChannelId": "UCywL8mGqZfMuW1XHHd-CUAQ"
      }
    },
    {
      "kind": "youtube#playlistItem",
      "etag": "72qTy_1RhDBvYCSGlF_5SMdOn90",
      "id": "UExuQ2pQWTZhc21KR2JlWmpqMmYyNjFpbDI3SXZIbVIzQy5DMkU4NTY1QUFGQTYwMDE3",
      "snippet": {
        "publishedAt": "2019-05-26T15:31:23Z",
        "channelId": "UCywL8mGqZfMuW1XHHd-CUAQ",
        "title": "Adubo fácil e grátis para qualquer planta - Nova receita adubo casca de banana",
        "description": "O melhor adubo natural para todas as plantas, um fertilizante caseiro que pode ser usado em qualquer planta, melhor adubo líquido..\nLivro do Cantinho de casa: https://www.cantinhodecasa.com\nVocê sabe qual é o conteúdo do guia do Cantinho de casa?\n\n1 - Como ter uma frutífera em vaso produzindo em 21 dias\n2 - Quais são todas as frutíferas que vc pode plantar em vaso\n3 - Como escolher a muda perfeita para plantar\n4 - Técnicas diferentes de como fazer mudas sem gastar nada e vantagens e desvantagens de cada uma\n5 - As principais pragas do pomar e receitas caseiras de como acabar com o problema\n6 - Técnicas de aceleração da produção de frutíferas\n7 - Técnicas de poda e como e quando usar cada uma\n8 - Adubação qual é o papel de cada nutriente\n9 -  E muito mais +++++\n\nO conteúdo te interessou? \n\nA vantagem do meu guia é que você terá acesso vitalicio a ele, todas as atualizações novos capítulos que forem surgindo e materiais bônus vc vai ganhar sem pagar mais nada por isto.\nDe bônus vc bai ganhar:\n\n1 - Bônus e-book de condicionamento de solo para suas plantas absorverem o máximo de nutrientes da terra\n2 - Bônus e-book de como cultivar morango em marmitex para bombar a produção\n3 - Bônus Participar do grupo do Whatsapp fechado do Cantinho de casa\n\nSe vc não gostar do livro eu te devolvo 100% do seu dinheiro de volta sem pegadinha e continuamos amigos! ok?\n\nA garantia de devolução é de 7 dias!\n\npara concluir vc deve acessar a página de vendas por este link: https://www.cantinhodecasa.com\n\n\nINSCREVA-SE: https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCywL8mGqZfMuW1XHHd-CUAQ?sub_confirmation=1",
        "thumbnails": {
          "default": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/R-X6kjXCMRs/default.jpg",
            "width": 120,
            "height": 90
          },
          "medium": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/R-X6kjXCMRs/mqdefault.jpg",
            "width": 320,
            "height": 180
          },
          "high": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/R-X6kjXCMRs/hqdefault.jpg",
            "width": 480,
            "height": 360
          },
          "standard": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/R-X6kjXCMRs/sddefault.jpg",
            "width": 640,
            "height": 480
          },
          "maxres": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/R-X6kjXCMRs/maxresdefault.jpg",
            "width": 1280,
            "height": 720
          }
        },
        "channelTitle": "Cantinho de casa",
        "playlistId": "PLnCjPY6asmJGbeZjj2f261il27IvHmR3C",
        "position": 1,
        "resourceId": {
          "kind": "youtube#video",
          "videoId": "R-X6kjXCMRs"
        },
        "videoOwnerChannelTitle": "Cantinho de casa",
        "videoOwnerChannelId": "UCywL8mGqZfMuW1XHHd-CUAQ"
      }
    },
    {
      "kind": "youtube#playlistItem",
      "etag": "KRiccxIb27DPxEPeUsUsqUwKRUA",
      "id": "UExuQ2pQWTZhc21KR2JlWmpqMmYyNjFpbDI3SXZIbVIzQy40QzRDOEU0QUYwNUIxN0M1",
      "snippet": {
        "publishedAt": "2019-08-28T00:22:38Z",
        "channelId": "UCywL8mGqZfMuW1XHHd-CUAQ",
        "title": "Melhor Forma Fazer Muda de Rosa",
        "description": "Aprenda como é facil fazer mudas de rosas com estas deicas da especialista no assunto minha tia Cida já fez mais de 100 mudas de rosas e nunca uma muda de rosa que ela fez deu errado, como vc pode ver no vídeo o processo de criação das mudas de rosas é muito simples e as mudas de rosas já começam a florir em pouquissimo tempo! Se gostar do vídeo compartilhe com seus amgigos e MUITO OBRIGADO POR ASSISTIR ESTE VÍDEO!\nVEM AI O LIVRO GUIA DE CULTIVO DE FRUTÍFERAS EM VASO(o livro mais completo sobre cultivo de frutíferas em vaso) quem se interessar me passe seu e-mail clicando neste link: https://forms.gle/1V4uH4Rbuqe2cwAm9  abraços!!!\n\n\n\nINSCREVA-SE no canal! Vem comigo e vamos chegar a 100 MIL INSCRITOS! https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCywL8mGqZfMuW1XHHd-CUAQ?sub_confirmation=1",
        "thumbnails": {
          "default": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/Mop_QZmVwTY/default.jpg",
            "width": 120,
            "height": 90
          },
          "medium": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/Mop_QZmVwTY/mqdefault.jpg",
            "width": 320,
            "height": 180
          },
          "high": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/Mop_QZmVwTY/hqdefault.jpg",
            "width": 480,
            "height": 360
          },
          "standard": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/Mop_QZmVwTY/sddefault.jpg",
            "width": 640,
            "height": 480
          },
          "maxres": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/Mop_QZmVwTY/maxresdefault.jpg",
            "width": 1280,
            "height": 720
          }
        },
        "channelTitle": "Cantinho de casa",
        "playlistId": "PLnCjPY6asmJGbeZjj2f261il27IvHmR3C",
        "position": 2,
        "resourceId": {
          "kind": "youtube#video",
          "videoId": "Mop_QZmVwTY"
        },
        "videoOwnerChannelTitle": "Cantinho de casa",
        "videoOwnerChannelId": "UCywL8mGqZfMuW1XHHd-CUAQ"
      }
    },
    {
      "kind": "youtube#playlistItem",
      "etag": "EdiCppL4GKKUOfZPX5IKnVNgXnE",
      "id": "UExuQ2pQWTZhc21KR2JlWmpqMmYyNjFpbDI3SXZIbVIzQy4yQUJFNUVCMzVDNjcxRTlF",
      "snippet": {
        "publishedAt": "2019-08-28T00:22:38Z",
        "channelId": "UCywL8mGqZfMuW1XHHd-CUAQ",
        "title": "COLOQUE ARROZ NA ORQUÍDEA! (Prova de Fogo)",
        "description": "Sua orquídea não está se desenvolvendo, \nnão dá mais flores e esta ficando feia? \nHoje eu estou muito feliz pois trago algumas super dicas incríveis para vc fortalecer sua orquídea, fazer ela se desenvolver \ne dar mais flores com adubação com arroz pois ajuda tanto no enraizamento quanto no florescimento. \nEntão se vc gosta deste tipo de assunto não perca tempo e clique no botão gostei para que o youtube recomende mais sobre este\nassunto para vc. E compartilhe este vídeo com seus amigos, para que o máximo de pessoas possam ver pois eles com certeza vou\nte agradecer muito. Vamos lá!\nCom esta super adubação sua orquídea irá florir o ano todo! esta adubação não foi inventada por mim e ela já é utlizada \nhá varios anos por produtores desta planta maravilhosa.\n\nMuita Atenção! dicas em relação a cuidados, orquídes não se planta na terra e existe um substrado específico para isto!\nAnote ai as orquideas não gostam de sol pleno! se vc fizer isto ela pode murchar e acabar morrendo!\nela gosta de sombra e de bastante claridade, e isto pode ser o diferencial para o sucesso! sempre a coloque em lugares com\nmuita claridade! outra dica super importante! orquíde não gosta de terra incharcada e isto pode causar o apodrecimento\ndas raizes dela! adube com a receita no máximo de 3 em 3 dias, mas não enxarque pois a planta pode morrer!\n\nAgora a dica matadora! É possivel adubar a orquidea com aqua de arroz, vc vai pegar meio copo de arroz e misturar com\nmeio copo de aqua misture muito bem(pode ser agua de lavagem de arroz também) peneire a solução de deixe descancar por 5 horas\nApós isto vc já pode adubar a sua planta 3 vezes por semana! não utilize esta agua por mais de 3 dias pois a solução pode \nazedar e acabar prejudicando a sua planta! Nesta agua vai ter magnésio, ferro, amido, zingo e diversos outros nutrientes que\nvão ajudar na floração e principalmente no enraizamento! então se vc gostou das dicas clique em gostei e compartilhe \no vídeo com o máximo de pessoas que amam esta planta maravilhosa e até o proximo vídeo.\nINSCREVA-SE no canal! Vem comigo e vamos chegar a 100 MIL INSCRITOS! https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCywL8mGqZfMuW1XHHd-CUAQ?sub_confirmation=1",
        "thumbnails": {
          "default": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/tpfCTzq_TEI/default.jpg",
            "width": 120,
            "height": 90
          },
          "medium": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/tpfCTzq_TEI/mqdefault.jpg",
            "width": 320,
            "height": 180
          },
          "high": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/tpfCTzq_TEI/hqdefault.jpg",
            "width": 480,
            "height": 360
          },
          "standard": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/tpfCTzq_TEI/sddefault.jpg",
            "width": 640,
            "height": 480
          },
          "maxres": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/tpfCTzq_TEI/maxresdefault.jpg",
            "width": 1280,
            "height": 720
          }
        },
        "channelTitle": "Cantinho de casa",
        "playlistId": "PLnCjPY6asmJGbeZjj2f261il27IvHmR3C",
        "position": 3,
        "resourceId": {
          "kind": "youtube#video",
          "videoId": "tpfCTzq_TEI"
        },
        "videoOwnerChannelTitle": "Cantinho de casa",
        "videoOwnerChannelId": "UCywL8mGqZfMuW1XHHd-CUAQ"
      }
    },
    {
      "kind": "youtube#playlistItem",
      "etag": "fBS9fUqPqiXeBcV-O9GXiStkMow",
      "id": "UExuQ2pQWTZhc21KR2JlWmpqMmYyNjFpbDI3SXZIbVIzQy4yQjZFRkExQjFGODk3RUFD",
      "snippet": {
        "publishedAt": "2019-08-28T00:22:38Z",
        "channelId": "UCywL8mGqZfMuW1XHHd-CUAQ",
        "title": "FLOR DO DESERTO (Guia Completo) Plantio, Propagação, Adubação, Cuidados e dicas",
        "description": "Confira agora este guia completo da flor do deserto também conhecida como rosa do deserto para saber como deixar suas plantas lindas e muito floridas. NÃO PERCA A SURPRESA NO FINAL DO VÍDEO! \nEsta planta é um dos melhores presentes para vc dar para as pessoas que vc ama.\n\nAssine o Cantinho de Casa: https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCywL8mGqZfMuW1XHHd-CUAQ?sub_confirmation=1",
        "thumbnails": {
          "default": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/vSy7Qkv2oTU/default.jpg",
            "width": 120,
            "height": 90
          },
          "medium": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/vSy7Qkv2oTU/mqdefault.jpg",
            "width": 320,
            "height": 180
          },
          "high": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/vSy7Qkv2oTU/hqdefault.jpg",
            "width": 480,
            "height": 360
          },
          "standard": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/vSy7Qkv2oTU/sddefault.jpg",
            "width": 640,
            "height": 480
          }
        },
        "channelTitle": "Cantinho de casa",
        "playlistId": "PLnCjPY6asmJGbeZjj2f261il27IvHmR3C",
        "position": 4,
        "resourceId": {
          "kind": "youtube#video",
          "videoId": "vSy7Qkv2oTU"
        },
        "videoOwnerChannelTitle": "Cantinho de casa",
        "videoOwnerChannelId": "UCywL8mGqZfMuW1XHHd-CUAQ"
      }
    }
  ],
  "pageInfo": {
    "totalResults": 65,
    "resultsPerPage": 5
  }
}
```

Reference: [PlaylistItems: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list)